# javax.servlet.ServletException: No action config found for the specified url

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, struts-1

---

RegAction.java

```
 private static final String FORWARD_succ = "succ";
Connection con=null;
public Connection getcon()
    {
    try
        {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","root");
        }catch(SQLException e)
        {}
        catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
        {
        }
        return con;
    }

    public void closeConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            con.close();
        }catch(SQLException e)
        {}
    }
   public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException 
  {
   RegForm1 r=(RegForm1)form;
     Connection con=getcon();

 String v1=r.getFname();
 String v2=r.getLname();
   String v3=r.getUid();
   String v4=r.getDob();
  String v5=r.getPwd();
  String v6=r.getCpwd();
   String v7=r.getCity();
  String v8=r.getSt();
  String v9=r.getZc();
 System.out.println(v1);
 System.out.println(v2);
 System.out.println(v3);
  System.out.println(v4);
 System.out.println(v5);
 System.out.println(v6);
 System.out.println(v7);
 System.out.println(v8);
  System.out.println(v9);

 try
{
PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
  Statement ps=con.createStatement();
   int k=ps.executeUpdate("insert into reg values(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9)");
    if(k==1)
      pw.println("susccessfully stored");
       con.commit();
}catch(SQLException s)
{
}

catch(IOException s)
{
}
  return mapping.findForward("succ");
```

config.xml

```
  <form-bean name="regform" type="RegForm1"/>
  </form-beans>
  <global-exceptions/>
  <global-forwards/>
  <action-mappings>
   <action name="regform" path="/reg" type="RegAction" validate="true input="/Register.jsp">
    <forward name="succ" path="/success.jsp"/>
```

Iwant to store the following field values in mysql database. but i am getting the following exception why?

NEW USER DETAILS
Firstname*: 
Lastname*:

userid* :

Dob* :

password* :

confirmpassword*

city*:

state*:

Zipcode*:

Button

HTTP Status 500 -

---

```
type Exception report
message 
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException
    org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:286)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
root cause 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    RegAction.execute(RegAction.java:75)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
    org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/5.5.29 logs.
```

---

Apache Tomcat/5.5.29

Comment: I guess you are using Struts, not struct. Did you check url mapping in struts-config.xml?

Comment: i am using struts1.x only            <html:form action ="/reg.do">  <action name="regform" path="/reg" type="RegAction" validate="true" input="/Register.jsp">

Comment: Show the code of RegAction class and your struts-config.xml file.

Comment: private static final String FORWARD_succ = "succ";
 Connection con=null;
 public Connection getcon()
  {
  try
   {
  
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","root");
   }catch(SQLException e)
   {}
   catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
   {
   }
   return con;
  }                                see futher

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the whole RegAction class and struts-config.xml file. And use code brackets that the code will be easy readable.

Comment: i can't see the <form-property> tags inside your <form-bean name="regform" type="RegForm1"/></form-bean> tag of your config?!

Answer (score 1):

SIVA..

```
int k=ps.executeUpdate("insert into reg values(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9)");
```

in the above statement `V1,V2,v3...` are treated as strings values instead of that use `PrepareStatement`..
Otherwise rewrite code like this

```
int k=ps.executeUpdate("insert into reg values('"+v1+"','"+v2+"','"+ . . );
```

if there are any numerical values in your list(v1,v2,v3..) no need to put `''` code ..
hope u got this..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually very hard to read. My guess is that this line: `Statement ps=con.createStatement();` cause `NPE`. Considering that you ignoring exceptions in your `getCon` method it is hard to say. You definitely should not ignore those type of exceptions. You should log them and see what is the exact exception. Use some logging framework to do that, or just simply print the stack trace to see it your self.

```
catch(SQLException e) {
   //log the exception
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException c) {
   //log the exception    
}
```

I think that your connection in your `getCon` method is returned as `null`. You should check if there are not any problem with your database connection.

Comment: what should i do in my coding

Comment: Your config seems to be ok, but there is quote missing, check this: validate="true".